# Running a PHP script that runs a Python script that runs a bash script, hangs on bash

Tags: php, python, bash, shell

I have a Python script which is encoding a video and then calling a shell script which uploads the new video to dropbox.  It works fine from the command line but I needed to make it so others could execute it so I have a PHP script calling the python script.

I don't want the PHP script to run forever (it takes 15-30 mins for it to complete), I just want it to kick off the python script and be done.  I figured out what I need to make that happen and like I said it works on the command line.  But when it is called via PHP, the video encodes but the file never uploads.  I can see the dropbox script was kicked off and is listed as a process using some percent of CPU, that percent never changes, it seems stuck/dead.

the command looks like this, being run using cmd()

`script.py -options &>/logs/phptopython.log &`

The shell script is kicked off using Popen

Any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: Maybe see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Comment: Sup dawg, I heard you like scripts.

Comment: LOL @BrenBarn. Your comment reminded me of https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHPPHP

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this could be a permissions issue. Double check the permissions on the directory to which you are trying to upload the video. If you are on Linux you can modify the permissions on that directory like this:

```
chmod 755 /path/to/dir
```

This gives the file owner read, write and execute permissions (7). The group and other users get read and execute permissions (5).

Apache is likely running as a different user than when you run the command yourself in bash. A quick test to see if it's a permission issue would be to grant 777 on that directory. I wouldn't leave it that way though – it'd just be a way to quickly identify if permissions are the issue.

If the script works with 777 permissions, you could either change the owner of the directory to the user Apache runs as or add the Apache user to the directory's group and grant the group write permisssions.

**Edit:**
I just noticed you said you use cmd(), so I'm guessing you are on Windows. My comments might still be relevant but the chmod command won't work on Windows.

Comment: I am on linux, I mis-typed, exec() is the PHP command used, not cmd().  It is not a permissions issue, directory is already 777. Also www-data is calling the Python script which is calling ffmpeg to encode the file to that same directory (so if it can write the file there, you'd think it could access it to ulpoad as well).

Comment: OK awesome. You can also try checking the Apache error logs. Maybe it has an error that can point you in the right direction. Apache error logs are usually somewhere like /var/log/apache/error.log.

Comment: Nothing in the error log. FWIW nothing gets written to the log file in the command either.  `&>/logs/phptopython.log &` When I run it via cmd line I do get output there.  And looking in webmin > processes, both commands are still there from hours ago, same CPU %.

Comment: Are you closing your pipe at the end of the script? If so, I guess it just isn't reaching that point. I've used this once before to run a process in the background and close it when it's done: plcose(popen('script.py', 'r'));

Comment: It seems to have something to do with the redirecting of the output & making it so the PHP ends quickly. Before I added that, the PHP script ran and ran but it did fully finish. The is the Python that calls the script `process = Popen(script.sh, STDOUT=PIPE)` `process.communicate()` `exit_code = process.wait()`

Comment: I just terminated the shell script via webmin (running since whenever yesterday), the email that it sends when it finishes was sent (this is part of the python script) when I did that.  But the shell script didn't do the upload.  I guess a Python way to upload to dropbox would solve my problem.

Comment: Yeah I mean, ideally you wouldn't have to call a script that runs a script that runs...you get it. Good luck finding a solution!